# changing output format in SCILAB

Tags: scilab

I want to change the output format in SCILAB, tried with different mode() already
but still get the results as below.

```
--> a=factorial(20)
 a  = 

   2.433D+18
```

Comment: have you looked into [format](https://help.scilab.org/docs/6.0.1/ja_JP/format.html)?

Comment: hi , i tried format but no luck

Comment: please explain how want it to be, I will provide the required syntax for [format](https://help.scilab.org/docs/6.0.1/ja_JP/format.html).

Comment: it should be in regular format , non engineering format if it is called?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately [the Scilab's `format` function page](https://help.scilab.org/docs/6.0.1/ja_JP/format.html) is not very updated. The complete syntax is:

```
[ResultMode, ResultWidth]  = format(InputMode, InputWidth)
```

where `InputMode` is a string with accepted values of `"v"` for "adaptive formatting" and `"e"` for

> exponential/engineering/scientific notation (e.g. -1.438E+02)

The `InputWidth` should be a positive integer between `1-25` indicating the number of digits. Both inputs are optional by the way.  The `ResultMode` is an integer of `1` for adaptive and `0` for exponential formatting. The `ResultWidth` is also a positive integer.

The issue is that setting `InputMode` to `"v"` does not guaranty you the normal notation unless you have specified enough `InputWidth`. In this case your result has 19 digits:

> 2,432,902,008,176,640,000

for some reason you have to specify a `InputWidth` of 21 digits:

```
format("v", 21);
```

to get what you are looking for:

```
--> a = factorial(20)
 a  = 

   2432902008176640000.
```